# Picklist field value updation based on checkbox field

Tags: trigger

In Account object I have 2 fields :

- `check__c` (checkbox field)
- Rating (Picklist field)

  1. When I am creating a new record or updating a existing record on that time, I enable the checkbox field then save the record, the Rating field will automatically update to Hot and again i am updating the same record
  2. If I disable the checkbox field, Rating field will automatically update to Worm

I tried some code like this:

```
trigger updatepicklstbsdoncheckbox on Account (before insert,before update) {

   for(Account acc :Trigger.new){
      Account a = [select id,Testing__c,Rating from Account ]; 
      if(a.Testing__c == true){
         a.Rating = 'Hot';
      } else if(a.Testing__c == true) {
         a.Rating = 'Worm';
      }   
   } 
}
```

but I am getting trigger error

> Error: Apex trigger updatepicklstbsdoncheckbox caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: updatepicklstbsdoncheckbox: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject: Trigger.updatepicklstbsdoncheckbox: line 4, column 1

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but I think the answer might be "workflow rule." Could you clarify exactly what your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers have a specific context that they execute in. This context includes certain variables which are not accessible in other contexts (such as visualforce pages). Specifically, everything associated with the `Trigger` class, such as `Trigger.new`.

Inside this context, modifying the records provided by `Trigger.new` will modify the data being saved to the database. It also includes all field values for the records.

Basically, you don't need to query for each record (especially not in a loop in a trigger). You also aren't filtering your query down to a single record, which is where the error comes from.

Instead of trying to get query the values, use the data already in context:

```
   for(Account acc :Trigger.new){
      if(acc.Testing__c){
         acc.Rating = 'Hot';
      } else if(!acc.Testing__c) {
         acc.Rating = 'Worm';
      }   
   }
```

Comment: +1. OP's `if` logic is also broken, though, so it still won't work as such.